# Limit of a function of two variables: $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0}\dfrac{x^2y}{17x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, closed-form

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \dfrac{x^2y}{17x^2+y^2}$$

I want to obtain this limit but don't know how to. The most general advice I've found is to convert this function into polar coordinates, so when I do that I get $$\lim_{r \to 0} \dfrac{r \cos^2 x \sin x}{17\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x}$$

but I don't think this is correct either. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, it is good. The bottom is clearly $\ge 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why? I don't think it's correct in general  to convert this into something like $\lim_{r\to 0}\text{stuff}$ (in this form of wording I'd assume fixed $\theta$). Because even $\lim_{r\to 0}\text{stuff}$ exists, it may not imply the original limit exists. There are examples like the limits depend on choice of $\theta$.

Comment: The proof shows it exists. For (after the cancellation of $r^2$ that OP did)  we have an expression whose top has absolute value $\le r$, however $\theta$ varies, and yes, $\theta$  can vary, and whose bottom is $\ge1$, again whatever $\theta$ might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you may then observe that
$$
\left|\dfrac{r \cos^2 x \sin x}{17\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x}\right|=\left|\dfrac{r \cos^2 x \sin x}{16\cos^2 x+ 1}\right|\leq \left|r \cos^2 x \sin x\right| \leq r
$$ and let $r\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For any $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, we have $0 \le \dfrac{x^2}{17x^2+y^2} \le \dfrac{1}{17}$.

Hence, $-\dfrac{1}{17}|y| \le \left|\dfrac{x^2y}{17x^2y}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{17}|y|$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Now, apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is good. The bottom is clearly $\ge 1$, and $|\cos^2 x\sin x|\lt 1$. So as $r\to 0$, the expression goes to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AM-GM inequality, so that
$$
\left|\frac{x^2y}{17x^2+y^2}\right| \le \left|\frac{x^2y}{2\sqrt{17}xy}\right|=\frac{|y|}{2\sqrt{17}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=kx$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Now $x \rightarrow 0$ does the trick.